# Pass if statement outcome to blade

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to access from Controller values to my blade

```
public function show(Template $template){

    if (Save::where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)->count() > 0) {
        if (Save::where('title', '=', $template->title)->count() > 0) {
            //OUTPUT -  EXISTS
         } 
            //OUTPUT -  NOT EXISTS
     } 


    return view('actions/show', [
        'template' => $template
    ]);
}
```

How am I able to call these if statement value in show.blade.php, so I be able to make from this:

```
<form action="/save/{{$template->unique_key}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <button><i class="bi bi-heart-fill"></i></button>
</form>
```

To this

```
if($save == 'notExists')
    <form action="/save/{{$template->unique_key}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <button><i class="bi bi-heart-fill"></i></button>
    </form>
@else
    ALREADY SAVED
@endif
```

Comment: Maybe make a boolean in the if statement and pass it to the view (just like you do with the template variable), then in the view check the value of the boolean and display the form accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller file. You have to have an `if-else` statement as well as assign a variable.

In your controller, change your code to this.

```
public function show(Template $template){

    if (Save::where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)->count() > 0) {
        if (Save::where('title', '=', $template->title)->count() > 0) {
            $exists = true;
         } 
         else {
            $exists = false;
     } 


    return view('actions/show', [
        'template' => $template, 'exists' => $exists
    ]);
}
```

Now in your view file you can access it this way

```
if(!$exists)
    <form action="/save/{{$template->unique_key}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <button><i class="bi bi-heart-fill"></i></button>
    </form>
@else
    ALREADY SAVED
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be shortened:

```
public function show(Template $template)
{
    $save = Save::where('user_id', auth()->id())->exists() 
        && Save::where('title', $template->title)->exists();

    return view('actions/show', compact('template', 'save'));
}
```

*show.blade.php*

```
@if(!$save)
    <form action="/save/{{$template->unique_key}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <button><i class="bi bi-heart-fill"></i></button>
    </form>
@else
    ALREADY SAVED
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below. you are using same query multiple time.

```
public function show(Template $template){
 $save= false;
if (Save::where(['user_id'=> auth()->user()->id,'title', => $template->title])->count() > 0) {
  $save= true;
 } 


return view('actions/show', [
    'template' => $template,"save"=>$save
]);
}
```

In blade it will be like this.

```
 if(!empty($save)){
     //exit 
    }else{ 
    //not exist
    }
```